# fail2ban fails 2 ban login attemps to smtp (postfix) server in docker container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, postfix, fail2ban

I got a problem with my host / docker setting as follows:
Host runs fail2ban, which accesses the mail.log files from the docker container, which are mapped over a volume. This all works fine, I defined a jail.local

```
[postfix-sasl]
enabled  = true
port     = smtpd
filter   = postfix-sasl
logpath  = /var/lib/docker/volumes/smtp2/_data/mail.log
bantime  = 604800
maxretry = 5
action = docker-action
```

and a filter postfix-sasl.conf

```
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf

[Definition]
_daemon = postfix(-\w+)?/(?:submission/|smtps/)?smtp[ds]
_port = (?::\d+)?
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)swarning: [-._\w]+\[<HOST>\]%(_port)s: SASL ((?i)LOGIN|PLAIN|(?:CRAM|DIGEST)-MD5)            authentication failed(:[ A-Za-z0-9+/:]*={0,2})?\s*$

ignoreregex = authentication failed: Connection lost to authentication server$
[Init]

journalmatch = _SYSTEMD_UNIT=postfix.service
```

and an action as docker-action.conf

```
[Definition]  
actionstart =
actionstop =
actioncheck = iptables -n -L FORWARD | grep -q 'DOCKER[ \t]'
actionban = iptables -I DOCKER 1 -s <ip> -j DROP
actionunban = iptables -D DOCKER -s <ip> -j DROP
```

All seems to work fine, even got

```
2018-08-14 16:51:24,048 fail2ban.actions        [26209]: WARNING [postfix-sasl] 181.214.206.133 already banned
```

and in iptables -S the following entry, as I wanted:

```
-A DOCKER -s 181.214.206.133/32 -j DROP
```

But in my container still all the attemps get in like this

```
Aug 14 17:34:28 smtp2 postfix/smtpd[16114]: warning: unknown[181.214.206.133]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Aug 14 17:34:29 smtp2 postfix/smtpd[16114]: disconnect from unknown[181.214.206.133] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
Aug 14 17:34:52 smtp2 postfix/smtpd[16114]: connect from unknown[181.214.206.133]
```

Output from iptables -S

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION
-N DOCKER-USER
-N f2bd-postfix-sasl
-N fail2ban-postfix
-N ufw-after-forward
-N ufw-after-input
-N ufw-after-logging-forward
-N ufw-after-logging-input
-N ufw-after-logging-output
-N ufw-after-output
-N ufw-before-forward
-N ufw-before-input
-N ufw-before-logging-forward
-N ufw-before-logging-input
-N ufw-before-logging-output
-N ufw-before-output
-N ufw-logging-allow
-N ufw-logging-deny
-N ufw-not-local
-N ufw-reject-forward
-N ufw-reject-input
-N ufw-reject-output
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-forward
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-output
-N ufw-track-forward
-N ufw-track-input
-N ufw-track-output
-N ufw-user-forward
-N ufw-user-input
-N ufw-user-limit
-N ufw-user-limit-accept
-N ufw-user-logging-forward
-N ufw-user-logging-input
-N ufw-user-loggireject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25 -j fail2ban-postfix
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A DOCKER -s 69.10.48.187/32 -j DROP
-A DOCKER -s 181.214.206.133/32 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

Output of iptables -vnL FORWARD | grep docker

```
0 0 ACCEPT all -- * docker0 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 ctstate  ELATED,ESTABLISHED 
0 0 DOCKER all -- * docker0 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 
0 0 ACCEPT all -- docker0 !docker0 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 
0 0 ACCEPT all -- docker0 docker0 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
```

Can anyone explain to me, why those requests are still getting forwared to the docker container? Am I missing out on something?

Comment: Where in iptables is the DOCKER chain called?

Comment: Does the Output from iptables -S  answer your question? Or is there anywhere else, I have to get the information from?

Comment: What is the output of `iptables -vnL FORWARD | grep docker`, after there have been connections to your docker container?

Comment: 0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Please add that to the question by using edit below the question.  This is barely readable.

Comment: Sure, sorry for that :-)

Comment: Could you share how your configuration looks like now, @JohnDaniels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DOCKER` chain is only called from `FORWARD`. As you can see from the numbers zero, the rules are not reached. Try to call the `DOCKER` chain from `INPUT`, too.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to do the Trick. Sorry, I sadly cant upvote yout answer due to my low reputation. But I am really grateful for your help :-)

Comment: @JohnDaniels what change did you do and how, to fix this. thanks.

Comment: Funny, it worked for me using the author's configuration. But how would one add this call from INPUT?